# Having a button on a containerView perform an action on an unrelated containerView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, delegates, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view controller (VC0) with 3 container views in it, being a 'left' view controller (VC1), a 'right' view controller (VC2), and a 'centre' collection view controller (VC3).

VC0 is embedded into a navigation controller and a 'left' and 'right' button configured. The centre view (VC3) will slide left or right when each button is pressed, revealing a menu on VC1 or VC2 underneath.

On the right 'menu' view controller (VC2) I want an 'edit' button. When the 'edit' button is pressed I want the centre panel to 'collapse' and move back to it's default position (which is not slid left or right) and the visibility of a view to be toggled on all the cells in the collection view controller (VC3). The goal is to put a 'delete' button on each cell which will become visible when the 'edit' button is pressed, so cells can be deleted one at a time by pressing the 'delete' button on each cell, and hidden when the user is done deleting cells.

I can get the edit button to collapse the centre view using a delegate, but I'm not sure how to change the visibility of a view on all cells when the edit button is pressed. I've tried using a delegate, and a closure, and a combination of both, but haven't had any luck. Here's what I have so far:

```
//VC0 - HOLDS CONTAINER VIEWS
import UIKit
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, RightPanelDelegate {

    func hideLabel() {
        let vc = CenterCollectionCV()
        vc.hideLabel()
    }

    func collapsePanel() {
        animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0, duration: 0.5, springDamping: 0.6) { _ in
            self.currentState = .bothCollapsed
            self.leftView.isHidden = true
            self.rightView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

```
// VC2 - RIGHT CONTAINER
import UIKit

protocol RightPanelDelegate {
    func collapsePanel()
    func hideLabel()
}

class RightPanelVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate: RightPanelDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.collapsePanel()
        delegate?.hideLabel()   
    }
}
```

```
//VC3 - CENTER CONTAINER
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CenterCollectionCV: UICollectionViewController {

        func hideLabel() {
        // I'VE TRIED TO ACCESS THE CELL TO HIDE THE LABEL
        // I'VE TRIED USING A CLOSURE IN THE CELL
        // I'VE TRIED USING A DELEGATE IN THE CELL
        // I CAN'T FIGURE OUT THE STEPS OR WORKFLOW REQUIRED
        // COMMON ERROR IS "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" which I think will be because I'm not targeting an already instantiated cell but instead creating a new cell instance, eg: 

        // myCell = CenterCell()
        // myCell.label.isHidden = true

// But all the other approaches I've tried haven't worked either.

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CenterCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

```
// COLLECTION VIEW CELL
import UIKit

class CenterCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
}
```

I'd like the end result to be having the view on the cells in a container hidden or shown when a button is pressed in another, unrelated container.

Any tips or assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create a delegate in VC0 (the view with multiple containers) and implementing it on the VC3 (the collectionView), which I'd already tried, but the key was adding a segue between VC0 and VC3 which set the delegate in VC0 to VC3. Once I did that, things worked. So the answer ultimately was that I didn't set up the delegate properly.

Code is now as follows:

```
//VC0 - HOLDS CONTAINER VIEWS
import UIKit

protocol ContainerViewControllerDelegate {
    func actionToPerform()
}

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, RightPanelDelegate {

    var delegate: ContainerViewControllerDelegate?

    func hideLabel() {
        let vc = CenterCollectionCV()
        vc.hideLabel()
    }

    func collapsePanel() {
        animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0, duration: 0.5, springDamping: 0.6) { _ in
            self.currentState = .bothCollapsed
            self.leftView.isHidden = true
            self.rightView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.destination is RightPanelVC {
            let vc: RightPanelVC = segue.destination as! RightPanelVC
            vc.delegate = self
        }

        if segue.destination is ViewController {
            let vc: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
            self.delegate = vc
        }
    }
}
```

```
//VC3 - CENTER CONTAINER
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CenterCollectionCV: UICollectionViewController, ContainerViewControllerDelegate {

    func actionToPerform() {
    // perform tasks related to collectionView or cell here
    collectionView.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CenterCell

        return cell
    }
}
```